# When will App.Path produce UNC notation?

Tags: vb6

Recently users of our VB6 app have encountered problems when trying to read files.

It surfaced that the Dir function throws an error for non-existing shares instead of returning an empty string.

My hunch is that previously the App.Path function returned "C:\Program Files\OurApp\ourapp.exe" but now it returns "\\MyComputer\C$\Program Files\OurApp\ourapp.exe". The Dir function raises an error if \\MyComputer\ does not exist.

Has anyone an idea when or how this undesirable behaviour is generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut your users start your app is pointing to `\\MyComputer\C$r\...` which explains why App.Path is in UNC notation.

**Who turned the shortcut in UNC?**

Ususally when an admin browses `\\MyComputer\C$` and finds a shortcut in `\\MyComputer\C$\Document and Settings\User\Desktop` or similar and start it, the shortcut automagically is reconciled not to point to local drive `C:` but to `\\MyComputer\C$`. Later local users being local admins don't find anything wrong such shortcuts and so on...